# Key code não pega a tecla ESC

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou fazendo uma função, para que quando seja pressionada uma tecla do teclado, ela execute outra função.
Com as teclas de letras, números e até o Enter funciona.
Porém com a tecla ESC não funciona.
Alguém já precisou fazer algo semelhante?

Segue código:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
    console.log(event.keyCode)
    if(event.keyCode == 27) {
        vm.fecha_modal();  
    }
})
```

Comment: Tenta asssim 

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) $('.save').click();     // enter
  if (e.keyCode === 27) $('.cancel').click();   // esc
});

Comment: @PauloHDSousa deu certo! se quiser pode por como resposta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenta asssim

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode === 27) 
        vm.fecha_modal(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo a utilizar a função abaixo `getCharCode` para resgatar o código do evento e depois, realizar a tratativa. O motivo de ter criado esta função é, em alguns browsers resgata o valor do código do evento com `keyCode`, em outros com `which`.

Então, criei um wrapper para ambos, assim terá uma compatibilidade maior de browsers. Para visualizar o código de cada tecla, clique sobre o campo e pressione as teclas.

Coloquei um `console.log` para apresentar os resultados. Com o código em mãos, basta escutar os eventos conforme nossos colegas informaram ou até mesmo, seguir o exemplo deste código.

```js
function getCharCode(e) {
  e = (e) ? e : window.event, charCode = null;

  try {
    charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    return charCode;
  } catch (err) {
    return charCode;
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log("Tecla pressionada %s (%s)", e.key, getCharCode(e));
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="" placeholder="Clique aqui e pressione as teclas" />
```